# VS code : Dynamic Values in Settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have an extension in vs code, uses the user custom xml file to run. I want to refer the xml file in my settings.json in a dynamic way. I want to put that xml file in my project folder and refer in Setings.json. Can you help me get this? thank you.